# SharePoint 2010 site is not opening with Alternate access mappings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, iis, alternate-access-mapping

My SharePoint site is not opening with any of public urls configured in Alternate access mapping.

Steps i followed,

1. I have added one public url for intranet zone eg: "http://www.example.com"
2. I have added IIS Binding (www.example.com) for site within IIS.

But, When i hit the above url in browser then browser show google search result Instead of opening SharePoint site.

Should i need to configure something else? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

- You have created your DNS
- Make Sure your DNS is pointing to your WFE or if you are using load balancer then point to it.
- also, make sure your AAM settings properly configured and no typo in it.
- finally, in the command prompt run this `tracert www.wxample.com`

Comment: There is no typo in AAM urls. Should i need to extend my web application for intranet zone?

Comment: Ok.what abt the dns?

Comment: Actually i dont know how to create DNS and how pointing it to WFE. can u please provide steps or any in depth article link.

Comment: first question, from where you get your url www.example.com?....do you have Domain server....http://blog.walisystemsinc.com/2012/11/sharepoint-2013-setup-dns-and-use-fqdn.html

Comment: I don't have domain server. let me clarify, I have installed SharePoint on my local machine(single server). I have created one web application ie "http://pc10:8585". I can able to access this site,No issue. But i just want to access this this site on my machine by "www.example.com" OR  "portal.example.com" .